# Limit of a function with 2 variables of the indeterminate form 0/0

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion, polar-coordinates, indeterminate-forms

For my vector calculus course, I need to solve this limit: $$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{1-\cos(x^2y)}{x^6+y^4}$$

By replacing (x,y) by (0,0), I noticed that the limit was of the form $\frac{0}{0}$ and decided to Taylor expand the numerator which gave me this inequality: $$\left | 1-\cos(x^2y) \right |\leq\frac{x^4y^2}{2}$$

Then I rewrote my limit using the inequality I just found: $$\left | \frac{1-\cos(x^2y)}{x^6+y^4} \right |\leq \frac{x^4y^2}{2(x^6+y^4)}\leq \frac{x^4y^2}{x^6+y^4}$$

Seeing that I was stuck, I decided to rewrite my expression in polar coordinates: $$\left | \frac{1-\cos(x^2y)}{x^6+y^4} \right |\leq\frac{(r\cos(\theta))^4(r\sin(\theta))^2}{(r\cos(\theta))^6+(r\sin(\theta))^4}$$

By making some simplifications, I get: $$\frac{(r\cos(\theta))^4(r\sin(\theta))^2}{(r\cos(\theta))^6+(r\sin(\theta))^4}=\frac{r^2\cos^4(\theta)\sin^2(\theta)}{r^2\cos^6(\theta)+\sin^4(\theta)}$$

And when I take the limit of my new expression when r tends to 0, I get: $$\lim_{r\to 0} \frac{r^2\cos^4(\theta)\sin^2(\theta)}{r^2\cos^6(\theta)+\sin^4(\theta)} = \frac{0}{\sin^4(\theta)}=0$$ unless $\theta=k\pi$ where $k \epsilon \mathbb{Z}$

First, I wanted to know if my proof was correct and if it is not, where was my mistake. Second, I wanted to know if there was a proof without the condition that $\theta=k\pi$.

Thank you in advance for your answers,

IsaacM

Comment: Hmmmm... how do you know the limit even exists?

Comment: In your first attempt, your $x^4 y^2$ mistakenly turned into $x^2 y^4$.

Comment: @angryavian Oh yes I made a mistake in copying what I had written. I'll change it right away ^^

Comment: @Riemann'sPointyNose I assumed the limit existed because later in my assignment, we define a function f(x,y) = (1-cos(x^2y))/x^6+y^4 when (x,y)≠(0,0) and f(x,y) = 0 when (x,y)=(0,0)

Comment: This is not correct. You're not suppose to take the limit $r \to 0$ for *fixed* $\theta$, since that's not the only way to approach the origin. What if $\theta$ depends on $r$ in such a way that $\sin^4 \theta \to 0$ too, as $r \to 0$?

Comment: @HansLundmark Yeah, that's what I thought but I didn't see any other way to do it

Comment: Same [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4258457/505767) was asked yesterday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible variant to do is, that knowing $1-\cos \alpha=2\sin^2 \frac{\alpha}{2}$ we have
$$\frac{1-\cos(x^2y)}{x^6+y^4} = \frac{2\sin^2 \frac{x^2y}{2}}{x^6+y^4}$$
So we can consider
$$\frac{x^4y^2}{x^6+y^4} \leqslant \frac{x^4y^2}{2|x|^3y^2}=\frac{1}{2}x\cdot\text{sign}(x)\to 0$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I don't understand how you get (x^4y^2)/(x^6+y^4) < (x^4y^2)/2abs(x)^3y^2

Comment: From $x^6+y^4\geqslant 2|x|^3y^2$ it is same with $(|x|^3-y^2)^2\geqslant 0$.

Comment: But how do you get this inequality?

Comment: Add to above comment.

Comment: Ok thank you very much for your answer